# Web based Report Designer Spring/Hibernate

Tags: spring, birt, jasperserver

I am looking for a web based report designer supporting spring/hibernate. I have seen BIRTStudio but it is not free.

I came across this list http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting which could be helpful. It might be appropriate to cookup my own small reporting engine. My core requirements:

- End user should be able to specify parameters for a report
- Report should be available in Excel form
- Report should use the same permissions scheme as the application (ie spring security)
- Report can be of two types (visual and textual) and among those types report can be of Chart or Map

Comment: Does the report designer need to be web based or just the interface to run the reports?

Comment: I am looking for a web based solution. There are few established open source desktop based clients, but web is easy to sell to management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found Pentaho to be a solution

http://community.pentaho.com/faq/waqr_faq.php

The target audience is not software developers, but it still seems a good start.

Answer (score 1):

@geoaxis, try Jasper and DynamicJasper

I've written a set of tutorials for integrating Spring MVC 3 and Jasper. I've also provided a downloadable Maven build.

http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html